# How can I prevent listings from replacing space characters by a weird bracket symbol?

Tags: listings

I'm using the `listings` package and I'm not happy about the output I'm getting. More specifically, `listings` seems to replace some space characters by a weird bracket symbol. See the screenshot below. Is there a way to make this symbol disappear?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{dkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{dkyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,.8,.3}

\lstset{
  language        = php,
  basicstyle      = \small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle    = \color{dkblue},
  stringstyle     = \color{red},
  identifierstyle = \color{dkgreen},
  commentstyle    = \color{gray},
  emph            =[1]{php},
  emphstyle       =[1]\color{black},
  emph            =[2]{if,and,or,else},
  emphstyle       =[2]\color{dkyellow}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
<?php
//PFBC 3.x PHP 5 >= 5.3
session_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/PFBC/Form.php");
$form = new PFBC\Form("GettingStarted");
$form->addElement(new PFBC\Element\Textbox("My Textbox:", "MyTextbox"));
$form->addElement(new PFBC\Element\Select("My Select:", "MySelect", array(
   "Option #1", //<--- here for example
   "Option #2",
   "Option #3"
)));
$form->addElement(new PFBC\Element\Button);
$form->render();

//PFBC 3.x PHP 5
session_start();
include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/PFBC/Form.php");
$form = new Form("GettingStarted");
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("My Textbox:",  "MyTextbox"));  (My Textbox
$form->addElement(new Element_Select("My Select:", "MySelect", array(
   "Option #1",
   "Option #2",
   "Option #3"
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button);
$form->render();
?>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a not a bracket; it's a symbol that marks the presence of a space character, which would otherwise be invisible. Use `showstringspaces=false` to make that symbol disappear.